# Modal logics which have an algebraic semantics but not a Kripke semantics

Tags: lo.logic, modal-logic

A colleague told me that there are modal logics which have an algebraic semantics of some kind but which do not have a Kripke semantics and in which both $\Box$ is not monotonic with respect to $\to$, in the sense that

$$\frac{\phi \to \psi}{\Box\, \phi \to \Box \,\psi} $$

fails and in which the rule of necessitation fails. My colleague could not recall which logics he had in mind.

Can anyone tell me of any interesting logics which have an algebraic semantics but not a Kripke semantics? Are any of these logics in which $\Box$ is not monotonic with respect to $\to$ and in which necessitation fails?

Answer (score 2):

There is a semantics based on [neighborhood frames](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Neighborhood_semantics). A logic of a class of neighborhood frames is not necessarily normal and even not necessarily monotone (i.e. closed under the ϕ→ψ / □ϕ→□ψ rule). On the other hand, any neighborhood frame (W,N) defines an algebra on the set of subsets of W; see [E.Pacuit. Neighborhood Semantics for Modal Logic, p.32](http://ai.stanford.edu/%7Eepacuit/classes/esslli/nbhdesslli.pdf).